# How do i write equation of arima(2,1,1)?

Tags: time-series, arima

I am not sure how to write out the equation for Arima(2,1,1) and also the back-shift notation. Anyone please, I really need it to  be solved.
This is my attemp.

$y_t=\varphi_1{By}_t+\varphi_2{By}_{t-1}+e_t-\theta_1{Be}_t$

Please let me know if the equation is correct.

Comment: You're missing the first difference part of the model. You've described an ARMA(2,1) time series model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B(x_{t}) = x_{t-1}$ denote the lag operator. Since you're differencing the response is a difference so define $z_{t} = y_{t}- y_{t-1}$ as the response.

Now, according to what you stated, $z_{t}$ is ARMA(2,1). So,

$z_{t} = \phi_{1} B(z_{t}) + \phi_{2} B^{2}(z_{t}) + \epsilon_t - \theta_{1} B(e_{t})$

Comment: do you mind expanding the equation into Y' form? i have phi (1) as -0.683, phi(2) as -0.4684 and theta as 0.4772

Comment: Hi: if I understand your question correctly, you can just put $y_{t} - y_{t-1}$ where $z_{t}$ is. Same thing with the parameter estimates. But maybe I'm not understanding your question ?